# Online lecture videos on QCD?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics

I would like to know if there are any online collections of lecture videos on QCD or non-Abelian QFT at a graduate level (at the level of volume 2 of Weinberg's QFT books?)

For example:
In String Theory I think this one by Shiraz is a great (only?) online resource -
http://theory.tifr.res.in/~minwalla/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Physics 253: Quantum Field Theory Lectures by Sidney R. Coleman. Recorded in 1975-1976.](http://www.physics.harvard.edu/about/Phys253.html)

It is rare that you can find on such advanced topics whole-semester courses that are video recorded, with the exception to Coleman's and Minwalla's lectures. What is usually available are at most 5 video lectures per topic that were given at different summer schools. Here is an example:

[QCD for Postgraduates, from CERN documet server, by Giulia Zanderighi, 2010](http://indico.cern.ch/conferenceDisplay.py?confId=83014)